# Binary file with field seperator ^A is not loading using SQLLDR

Tags: oracle-database, control-characters

I'm trying to upload .dat file to Oracle DB using SQLLDR. 
File data columns are separated by "^A". 
File charset is of binary.

```
bash-4.4$ file -i /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat
/tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Here is my CTL file

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE DETAILS_TEMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^A'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
IS_ID "decode(trim(:ISSUE_ID),null,0,to_number(trim(:IS_ID)))",
IS_NAME CHAR(1500) "trim(:IS_NAME)",
IS_STATUS "trim(:IS_STATUS)",
is_no_days_draft_status FILLER,....
```

But when I run the script, data is not loading
and the first column is read as the complete row,
not recognizing the field separator. 
And/or the error in SQLLDR is "Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DETAILS_TEMP, column IS_ID. Field in data file exceeds maximum length".

When I open this file in Notepad++,
the field separator is showing as "SOH". 
When I do `cat /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat`,
it is not showing anything as field separator.

I tried converting the file to UTF-8/ASCII by using "strings":

```
strings /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat > /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209_tmp.txt
```

but all columns are as new rows in the file it generated.

Converted file: `cat /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209_tmp.txt`:

```
IS ID
IS Name
IS Status...
```

The command

```
od -tc < /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat
```

reports

```
i   s   _   i   d 001   i   s   _   n  a   m   e 001   i   s
_   s   t   a   t   u   s 001
```

confirming that the field separator
is the character whose byte value is 001.

I could not upload the file I used to load data
due to security constraints. 
But I can provide more details.

Comment: By `^A` do you mean the character whose byte value is 001? if so, perhaps try octal escape `\001` instead

Comment: @steeldriver `bash-4.4$ od -tc < /tmp/t_details_all_data_20240209.dat | head
0000000   i   s   _   i   d 001   i   s   _   n  a   m   e 001   i   s   _   s   t   a   t   u   s 001` So it is 001. But still the same error in SQLLDR, Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DETAILS_TEMP, column IS_ID. Field in data file exceeds maximum length

Comment: OK so it looks like the correct way to specify may be may be `X'01'` - see for example [Text description of the illustration terminat.gif](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96652/img_text/terminat.htm)

Comment: ... although tbh your question doesn't really seem to be about Unix & Linux (and certainly not about bash) - you could try [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: (1) You say “data is not loading” and that you are getting an error message “Record 1: Rejected”. But you also say “the first column is read as the complete row, not recognizing the field separator.” It’s not clear to me that these statements are consistent (is it reading data from your file into the database or not?)  (2) Now and in general, please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) You can show us what your data look like without showing us your actual data.  Create a file that has ID 123, name “John Smith”, status “single”, etc., in the same format as your file, verify that it fails the same way as your actual file, and show us that.  (4) If you believe that converting something(?) to UTF-8/ASCII is a function of the `strings` program, you seriously misunderstand the function of the `strings` program.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, it works. I thought it is problem of how unix handling the charset/encoding of the file. But it is a code issue, field seperator i mentioned in sqlldr is not correct !